# ngclipboard deselect (or not select at all) text after copying

Tags: jquery, angularjs

From [example](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/mWRzJB?editors=1010) here my problem is that text stays selected when pressing button Copy. Everything works fine, I can paste table to excel and it looks good. But I don't want whole table being marked when copying.

Action on the button:

```
<button ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#tblRoomsOccupy">Copy</button>
```

It looks like this (after pressing button 'Copy'):

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this? So table will not be marked after pressing 'Copy'.

Answer (score 1):

First Add data-ngclipboard-success to your button, which is calling the onSuccess event.

```
<button ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#tblRoomsOccupy" data-ngclipboard-success="onSuccess(e);">Copy</button>
```

After that in your JS add onSuccess function:-

```
onSuccess = function(e) {
   e.clearSelection();
};
```

You May Want To You $scope depending upon your code.